# 2 separate onclick functions

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have been trying to make the second image animate, but it doesn't work. I created a class for the type of animation I will like to use and then called on the image onclick function to run the animation. Can you please take a look at my code and help me out

```
    class img{

    ImageView img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    ImageView img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);

    void fadeIn(){

        img1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        img2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
    }
    void slideOutLeft(){
        img1.animate().translationXBy(-2000f).setDuration(2000);
    }
    void slideOutDown(){
        img1.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(2000);
    }

}
public void made(View view){
    img Stop = new img();
    Stop.slideOutDown();
}

public void fade(View view){
    img Start = new img();

    Start.slideOutLeft();

}
```

Comment: Are you setting onClick from the xml?

Comment: Please share the error log if any ..or describe a little more than "but it doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

both animation method does not have `start()`. You must call `start()` to actually start the animation.

```
void slideOutLeft(){
        img1.animate().translationXBy(-2000f).setDuration(2000).start();
    }
    void slideOutDown(){
        img1.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(2000).start();
    }
```

**Be sure to set the click listener to your image to make this method call work.**